# How to make script run completely until done?

Tags: php, cron

I have a PHP script which scrapes data for a few thousand records in a mysql table. I go through each record using foreach on the data and for each record it scrapes value required and saves it under that record in the specified fields.

Why would my script, after a while, end up stopping when executing in browser and the page decides to load in index.php although that is no where to be required / included as a statement in the code. I have used the `set_time_limit(0)` and `ini_set('max_execution_time')` and used flush(), none of this seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: PHP has a run time, so if your script takes too long to complete it will just stop running. I believe default timer is set to 30 seconds

Comment: ^^ To add to @IamCavic  --  If it were run command line via `shell` or `crontab` .. There is no timeout

Comment: Define "a while". Perhaps your script is using too much memory, and is being killed by php?

Comment: Looking in your server logs might show you the error. Memory is a good guess.

Comment: Webservers also have time-limits.... just don't run long tasks in a web browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a php process that continues to run independently from apache (with a different parent pid) use nohub. Example:

exec('nohup php process.php < /dev/null &');